# java constructor accessing (if we have private constructor in child class)

Tags: java, class, constructor

I have a class A and class B which extends Class A.In class A I have a constructor "A" and in class B I have a constructor "B" and I have declare constructor "b" as private. Will it be able to access its super class constructor "A"?

```
class A {
    public A(){
    }
}
class B extend A{
    private B(){
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you try it yourself then let us know if you have any further questions...

Comment: My answer is no.can you give your suggestions???

Comment: Yes, it can. And it will in your current configuration! Even if you don't explicitly call it with `super()`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, B constructor will be able to call constructor of A.

```
class A {
    public A(){
    System.out.println("Hello A constructor");
    }
}
class B extends A{
    private B(){
    super();
    System.out.println("Hello B constructor");
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
    new B();
    }
}
```

Output -
Hello A constructor
Hello B constructor